# Problems with fit_transform. Error object has no attribute 'fit_transform'

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

Ok I have this code

```
import anchor

bm = anchor.BayesianModalities()
modalities = bm.fit_transform(data)
```

but shows me this error

> AttributeError: 'BayesianModalities' object has no attribute 'fit_transform'

What Can be it?

Comment: Have you tried using: from anchor import BayesianModalities, bm = BayesianModalities(), modalities = bm.fit_transform(data).  This could be completely off-track, just a suggestion.

Comment: Still shows me the same error

Answer (score 1):

This looks like an issue with the `README`, the method is actually `fit_predict` rather than `fit_transform`. Give the below a try.

```
import anchor

bm = anchor.BayesianModalities()
modalities = bm.fit_predict(data)
```

Comment: Can you also explain why I can't access BayesianModalities through anchor? I can't find the option in any of the anchor sub-menus.

Comment: I don't actually use `anchor` so I don't know how much help I'll be. Usually it's something to do with the install though, I would reinstall and check you're using the correct Python environment.